# Keeping data State ViewModels

Tags: android, performance, model-view-controller

So according to android developers: "Architecture Components provides ViewModel helper class for the UI controller that is responsible for preparing data for the UI. ViewModel objects are automatically retained during configuration changes so that data they hold is immediately available to the next activity or fragment instance."

In the code below there is an asynchronous class that gets called in deleteItem function. My question is this: Does ViewModel also handles the asynchronous calls made inside it or will cause memory leaks?

Thank you

```
public class BorrowedListViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

private final LiveData<List<BorrowModel>> itemAndPersonList;

private AppDatabase appDatabase;

public BorrowedListViewModel(Application application) {
    super(application);

    appDatabase = AppDatabase.getDatabase(this.getApplication());

    itemAndPersonList = appDatabase.itemAndPersonModel().getAllBorrowedItems();
}


public LiveData<List<BorrowModel>> getItemAndPersonList() {
    return itemAndPersonList;
}

public void deleteItem(BorrowModel borrowModel) {
    new deleteAsyncTask(appDatabase).execute(borrowModel);
}

private static class deleteAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<BorrowModel, Void, Void> {

    private AppDatabase db;

    deleteAsyncTask(AppDatabase appDatabase) {
        db = appDatabase;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(final BorrowModel... params) {
        db.itemAndPersonModel().deleteBorrow(params[0]);
        return null;
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Yes but you need to tell the View when the process has finished

Comment: @matio What do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would provide an example, probably you need to modify the code.
First you need a live data change and subscribe to that in your view. Then in the controller you post the value telling the subscriber that something appends. This way asynchronously the view would get alerted.

`private MutableLiveData<String> databaseLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();`

...

And in the `deleteAsyncTask` class you can add:

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
     databaseLiveData.postValue("some data deleted");
}
```

And in the `BorrowedListViewModel` class this method to access from the view add this method:

```
public LiveData<String> getChanger() {
        return databaseLiveData;
    }
```

In the view e.g.Activity add this:

```
 private BorrowedListViewModel mBorrowedListViewModel;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //...
    BorrowedListViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(BorrowedListViewModel.class);

    subscribe();
}

private void subscribe() {
    final Observer<String> liveDataChange = new Observer<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable final String message) {

            Log.d("Activity", message);
        }
    };

    liveDataChange.getChanger().observe(this, liveDataChange);
}
```

Hope this help.